# Run object globally in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6

How possibility to run object globally that I call from Objective C library in swift? I don't want to call it more than once each time I switch the view controller. Is it I need to call it from `appDelegate()` ?

```
var instanceOfUMCrypto: UMCrypto = UMCrypto()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a global singleton object, you can declare it globally in any `.swift` file (not in any class or function), like that:

```
import UIKit
let instanceOfUMCrypto = UMCrypto()

class SomeClass {
     someFunction() {
     }
}
```

After that, you can call `instanceOfUMCrypto` from anywhere and it won't be initialized more than once.